# CSS: change opacity of svg path on hover

Tags: css, svg, path

I would like to change opacity of an inline SVG path from CSS. Here is the code :

```css
canvas { background-color:#777;}

svg { position:absolute; top: 0px;left:0px;}

#circle:hover {opacity: 0.9;}
#square:hover {opacity: 0.9;}
```

```html
<canvas width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>

<svg height="300" width="300" pointer-events="none"  >
    <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" pointer-events="all" opacity="0.3"/>
    <path id="square" d="M150 150 H 250 V 250 H 150 L 150 150" opacity="0.3"/>
</svg>
```

As you'll notice, it works with the circle, but not with the path. My questions are:

- Why isn't it working with the path?
- What should I do to apply the hover opacity to the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The path inherits pointer-events="none" from its parent.
- The circle doesn't because it overrides that parent pointer-events value.

If you want something to respond to mouse events, don't have it set it as pointer-events none.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `pointer-events="none"` then it will work fine.
Pointing `none` The element does not react to pointer events. Hence it doesn't work.

See [details](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_pointer-events.asp)

```css
canvas { background-color:#777;}

svg { position:absolute; top: 0px;left:0px;}

#circle:hover {opacity: 0.9;}
#square:hover {opacity: 0.9;}
```

```html
<canvas width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>

<svg height="300" width="300"   >
    <circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" pointer-events="all" opacity="0.3"/>
    <path id="square" d="M150 150 H 250 V 250 H 150 L 150 150" opacity="0.3"/>
</svg>
```